# What is the role of 'a lot' and 'much' in my sentences?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, syntactic-analysis

Can we use adverbs before pronouns?

As we know adverbs are normally used to modify 'other adverbs' , 'verbs', and 'adjectives'. e.g (I'm feeling a lot better today.)

I consider 'a lot' and 'much' as adverbs and 'more' as pronoun in the following. **Is my analysis OK?**

> I earn *a lot* **more** than my sister does.
>
> I have *a lot* **more** in common with my friends than my family.
>
> I can't stand *much* **more** of this.
>
> I eat ***a lot** less* than I used to.

Comment: “A lot” is a noun phrase and “more” can be either a determinative, as here, or an adverb. In your examples “a lot more” is an NP in which the determinative “more” is functioning as a “fused determiner-head”, i.e. the functions of determiner and head are fused together into the single word “more” (cf. “a lot **more money”**). The same kind of analysis applies to “a lot less”.

Comment: In all of my sentences ' a lo' considered non phrase? But in oxford dictionary there is something different from what you was saying. :((

Comment: Dictionaries are okay for meanings, but for grammar they are generally useless. It’s important to distinguish word category and function. In “a lot more”, “a lot” is a noun phrase (that’s its category) and its function is that of 'pre-head modifier' to the fused determiner-head “more” (meaning more x, where x is a noun, e.g. "more money"). So the whole thing “A lot more” is just as much a noun phrase as the non-fused “a lot more money”

Comment: -1 for asking the same thing, several times, on ELL and then asking it here with no explanation as to why the ELL answers weren't satisfactory.

Comment: @BillJ I don't agree dictionaries are generally useless for grammar. Also, I will **never** call "a lot" a noun phrase when it is used as an adverb. If it is used as an adverb as in "I like him a lot" or "I earn a lot more than ...", they are adverbs modifying the verb (like) or more (determiner/adjective). I am getting tired of all new grammar terms which add nothing to the clarity of a sentence structure. English is neither perfect nor very advanced. That's why there are so many parts of speech called differently. In other languages, neither such confusion nor new terms coined that often.

Comment: @Rathony Many grammarians feel the same way as me about dictionaries, viz. they are fine for meanings but not for syntax. It's crucial to grasp the difference between 'category' (noun, verb, adjective etc.) and function (subject, object, determiner, modifier etc.). In "I like him a lot", "a lot" is an NP (note that it has the article "the") **functioning** as an adjunct of degree. And in "I earn a lot more than ...", it's still an NP but this time its function is that of pre-head **modifier** to the fused determiner-head “more". There is nothing new in any of the terms I have used.

Comment: @BillJ OK. Let's say there is nothing new. But what difference does it make? Especially to English learners? What's the difference between **adverb** and **adjunct of degree**? I don't see any difference there. Why would you call "a lot" a noun phrase when it is not used as a noun?

Comment: @Rathony May I ask, have you read any of the grammars by Huddleston & Pullum? They are very helpful in explaining syntax and the associated terminology.

Comment: @BillJ Shall we stop here? Moderators will come and remove the comments.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't consider *a lot* and *much* as Adverbs. They're actually a different part of speech -- **Quantifier** -- which wasn't discovered until after Donatus specified the [Eight Parts of Speech](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html), around the Fourth Century. So you're not playing with a full deck.

Quantifiers are a type of Determiner, like articles; they indicate amounts and have very special syntax. Treating them like adverbs just makes more problems. Like the presuppositions underlying this question.

Answer (score 2):

In comments BillJ wrote:

> “A lot” is a noun phrase and “more” can be either a determinative, as here, or an adverb. In your examples “a lot more” is an NP in which the determinative “more” is functioning as a “fused determiner-head”, i.e. the functions of determiner and head are fused together into the single word “more” (cf. “a lot **more money”**). The same kind of analysis applies to “a lot less”.

> It's crucial to grasp the difference between 'category' (noun, verb, adjective etc.) and function (subject, object, determiner, modifier etc.). In "I like him a lot", "a lot" is an NP (note that it has the article "the") **functioning** as an adjunct of degree. And in "I earn a lot more than ...", it's still an NP but this time its function is that of pre-head **modifier** to the fused determiner-head “more". There is nothing new in any of the terms I have used.

Answer (score 0):

Whether an adverb can modify a noun (pronoun) or not has been debated and there is no firm conclusion. For example,

> **Almost** (or **Nearly**) everybody came.

Some argue that here *almost* or *nearly* are adjectives modifying the pronoun *everybody*. Some also argue that they are adverbs modifying *everybody*. But, others argue they are adverbs that modify the determiner *every* rather than the pronoun *everybody*. Just because *everybody* is a one word doesn't mean they can't modify *every*. English parts of speech are not very clear cut and there could be more arguments based on how you analyze the parts of speech. Your examples:

> I earn a lot more **money** than my sister does.
>
> I have a lot more **things** in common with my friends than my family.
>
> I can't stand much more **things** of this.
>
> I eat a lot less **things / food** than I used to.

As you can see, if you insert appropriate words after the determiner *more* and *less*, they are not pronouns any more. They are determiners (adjectives). Also, you need to note that *more* and *less* could function as **adverbs**. Therefore, it is very hard to say they modify (pro)nouns.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I really appreciate your help. How about the role of ' a lot' and 'much' in all sentences? Could please kindly help me?

Comment: @MickeyMouse You can safely consider "a lot" and "much" as an adverb.

Comment: Thanks how about the @BillJ comment? he stated quite different idea.

Comment: @MickeyMouse He is basically saying the same thing with different terms. Don't worry too much about part of speech. It is as confusing as it gets.